# CakePHP Auth Deny Admin Routing Pages

Tags: cakephp, roles, authentication

I have been reading Stack Overflow questions all afternoon trying to figure this out..

I have a users controller with index/login/logout/register functions but also has admin_index/admin_add/admin_edit/admin_delete etc.

I have Auth component enabled and in my users_controller i am trying to deny access to the admin_* pages if the `Auth.User.role != 'admin'`, when i enable the `$this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';` it denies access to the site.com/admin/users/ page and also seems to kill the logout function even tho my account has the role set to admin.

However if i type the url in i get redirected back to the main homepage.

users_controller.php

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Users';

    function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
        $this->Auth->allow('register');
    }

    function isAuthorized() {
        if ($this->Auth->user('role') != 'admin') {
            $this->Auth->deny('admin_index','admin_view', 'admin_add', 'admin_edit','admin_delete');
        }
    }
```

app_controller.php

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login', 'admin'=>false);
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'logout');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'shows', 'action'=>'index');
        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
        $this->Auth->allow('home');
    }
```

My Second question relates to the way `$this->Auth->deny('page');` redirects the user, as far as i can tell it redirects to / but i need it to redirect back to the users controller.

Hope it all makes sense and i have provided enough info..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The root of your problem is probably your isAuthorized() method. This should simply return true or false, and indicates whether an authenticated user is AUTHORIZED to access a particular action.

It's difficult to say why you'd be redirected to the home page instead of the login page. But it's possible that you have other code somewhere that's messing things up.

Try modifying your code as below and see if that doesn't help get things working:

**app_controller.php**

```
<?php 
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $components = array('Session', 'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login', 'admin'=>false),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'logout'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller'=>'shows', 'action'=>'index'),
        'autoRedirect' => false,
        'authorize' => 'controller'
    );

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('home');
}

function isAuthorized() {
    if (!empty($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
        if ($this->Auth->user('role') != 'admin') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

**users_controller.php**

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Users';

function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('register');
}
?>
```

I moved all the Auth settings to the declaration in the $components variable because it seems cleaner and to make more sense to declare default values there. But this is more a matter of personal preference and it shouldn't have a real effect on the code's functioning.

Also, note that if you set `autoRedirect` to false, you'll have to redirect logged-in users manually in your Users::login() action, getting the `loginRedirect` value with `$this->Auth->redirect()`.

I don't see any reason why you should be sent to / when you're not logged in and you try to access a blocked action, but maybe it will be easier to figure out after you fix the above. ****

Comment: works treat!!! thanks! i did test login as a user and try and go to site.com/admin/users/ it denies me but still redirect me back to / instead of shows/index ... any ideas? or should i open a new question?

Comment: Is the user you logged in as an admin user, with role == 'admin'? If you want the user to be redirected to site.com/shows/ when they log in, remove the line from the AuthComponent config that reads 'autoRedirect' => false. Also, I just noticed that your logoutRedirect is strange. That should be the location the user is redirected to AFTER they log out. Maybe try removing the autoRedirect and logoutRedirect lines in AppController and see how things work after that.

Comment: if a regular user tries to access a `/admin/` page it fails to redirect properly. any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @waspinator - It's hard to say without seeing your code. I'd suggest creating a new question and including the code that you're having trouble with, rather than trying to solve it in these comments.

Answer (score -1):

you should do this like...

```
       function beforeFilter()
        {
        if($this->Auth->user('role')=='admin'){
         $this->Auth->allow('admin_view','admin_controls');//put your all admin actions separated by comma

         }
else
{
$this->Auth->allow('home');//put your all non-admin actions separated by comma
}


    }
```

hope it will work... if any problem let me know....

Comment: i just tried this solution out and now i cannot get to register page if not Auth'd and when logged in cannot get to any of the admin_ pages.

Comment: If user is logged with any other role he can see this pages too. The way i found is by using redirect if user dont have admin role. Auth->allow or Auth->deny both fail